# loop through VBA to repeat the process

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I have two sheets. One having warehouse(18 warehouse) and second having shop (50 Shops).

I need to map shops against warehouse within 200 KM.

I have written one code for the same but need to loop it. Code is mentioned below

Code will copy first warehouse from warehouse sheet and paste it against each all 50 shops in shop sheet.
Then one formula in the sheet (already updated in shop sheet) calculate the difference in KM between each shop and first warehouse. Then filtered out shops within 200 km, copy and paste (transpose) against first warehouse in warehouse sheet. Now I want to do same procedure for second warehouse then third till end. Please help

==================================

```
Sub RADIUS()


Worksheets("SHOP").Activate
AutoFilterMode = False
Range("f2:g4175").Clear
Worksheets("WAREHOUSE").Activate
Range("C2:d2").Select
Selection.Copy


Worksheets("SHOP").Activate
Range("f2:g4175").PasteSpecial _
Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


AutoFilterMode = True
Range("A1:h1").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=200"
Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _


Worksheets("WAREHOUSE").Activate


Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select


Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that after the sub declaration, I would include the following:

```
j = 2
While Worksheet("Warehouse").Range("C"&j) <> "" then
```

At the end of the loop, just above the End Sub, I would include the following:

```
j = j + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Dim j As Integer
j = 2
While Worksheets("PP").Range("C" & j) <> ""  then                             ===compile error: syntex error===